# Запятая. Необходима?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Ух ты! Яблоко(,) как настоящее!

Здравствуйте. Нужна запятая? Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) **Ух ты! Яблоко, как настоящее!**

(2) **Ух ты! Яблоко как настоящее!**

Возможны оба варианта, семантические оттенки разные.

**В первом варианте** связь бессоюзная, обозначается запятой. На первом месте **назывное** предложение, на втором — предложение с **оценочным** значением.

**Во втором варианте** простое предложение, запятой между подлежащим и сказуемым нет при наличии союза КАК.